# Windows 10 reenables and runs disabled services automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

my company gave me a computer with Windows 10 Pro on it. Now I want to disable some of the unneeded Windows services (like SMS Agent Service, Telemetry, Diagnostics, etc). Only I have administrative authority on the computer and no other user (even domain users) have. After I manually stop and 'disable' services using service manager, after some time (like 1 day or so), I find these services in running and reenabled (Automatic start) state. It drives me crazy.

What place I should be looking at to disable these services completely and also disable the thing (maybe security policy or scheduled job?) that reenables disabled services? Is there a common way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's windows that's reenabling it and not some third party add-on? Check Task scheduler to see if any task are scheduled also you could ask the IT people in your company.

Comment: Most likely these are changed by group policy. Also, you probably don't want to disable SMS Agent Service because it is needed if your company uses System Center to manage devices and software.